# how to fix $interpolate:interr error when I call http.post in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am working with AngularJS and facing $interpolate:interr error when I call a webservice using $http.post.

Here is my source:

```
myportletServices.factory('Usage', ['$http', '$sce', 'Settings', 'Alert', function($http, $sce, Settings, Alert){
    this.query = function(callback){
          var url = $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl(Settings.webServiceUrl + '/usage?userid=' + Settings.screenName);
          var http = $http.post(url); //--> Error occurs
          http.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              if (data.ok==true) {
                 if (callback)
                     callback(data.result)
              } else {
                  Alert.add('Alert', data.message);
              }
          });   

          http.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              Alert.add('Error', data);
          });
    };

    return this;
 }]);
```

Return from Server:

```
{
   "ok": true,
   "message": "",
   "result":
   [
       {
           "phoneid": xxxxxx,
           "phonenumber": xxxxxxxx,
           "planid": xx,
           "planname": "$29 Plan",
           "cap":
           [
               {
                   "stdcap": 165,
                   "datacap": 100,
                   "smscap": 0
               }
           ],
           "usage":
           [
               {
                   "stdusage": 97.99,
                   "datausage": 56.044,
                   "smsusage": 0
               }
           ]
       },
       {
           "phoneid": xxxxx,
           "phonenumber": xxxxx,
           "planid": xx,
           "planname": "Essentials $45 Plan",
           "cap":
           [
               {
                   "stdcap": 650,
                   "datacap": 1000,
                   "smscap": 6000
               }
           ],
           "usage":
           [
               {
                   "stdusage": 116.51,
                   "datausage": 253.339,
                   "smsusage": 63
               }
           ]
       },
       {
           "phoneid": xxxxx,
           "phonenumber": xxxxxxx,
           "planid": 80,
           "planname": "Medium $25 Pack",
           "cap":
           [
               {
                   "stdcap": 500,
                   "datacap": 1500,
                   "smscap": 6000
               }
           ],
           "usage":
           [
               {
                   "stdusage": 90.05,
                   "datausage": 115.237,
                   "smsusage": 108
               }
           ]
       }
   ]
}
```

Error message:

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.2/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7Busage…usage.planname%7D%7D&p1=TypeError%3A%20undefined%20is%20not%20a%20function
    at Error (native)
```

I found than the error related to using wrong expression format but my case happens when I get the result from the webservice. Does it happen because return data has special characters like dollar sign?

Please explain the error and give some help how to fix it.
Thanks, your help would be appreciated.

Comment: From the URL in the error, it says: `Can't interpolate: {{usage…usage.planname}}`.  Do you use the expression `{{usage…usage.planname}}` in your HTML? I'm not familiar w/the `...` syntax.

Comment: Ah, yes I have. Thanks for it. I will check it again.

Comment: @Sunil D I found out what was the real problem. There is a custom filter in my html and it made the error. It works fine when I got rid of the filter. Thank you again for your help.